# Query for fetching data from joining table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have 4 tables:

**Department**

```
Id
-----------
1
2
3
```

**Employee**

```
Id
----
a
b
c
d
e
```

**Dep2Employee**

```
DepId       EmployeeId
----------- ----------
1           a
1           b
2           c
2           d
3           e
```

**EmployeeHistory**

```
EmplId      ReportType Timestamp
----------- ---------- ----------
1           type1      12.12.12
1           type3      13.12.12
2           type2      14.12.12
3           type2      15.12.12
```

Is it possible to, in one LINQ (EF Core) expression, fetch all the reports of **type1** for all employees working in the **Department** with the given Id, ordered by timestamp?  Something like `GetAllReportsOfType1(string departmentId)`

It is also interesting how the SQL query would look like.

Thanks.

Comment: *Is it possible* -- Of course it is, using navigation properties will even make it pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeHistory His WHERE EmplId in ( SELECT DE.EmployeeId FROM Dep2Employee DE WHERE DE.DepId = '1')
 AND His.ReportType = 'type1'
```

LINQ

```
 context.Dep2Employee.Where(a => a.DepId == "1")
                .SelectMany(b => b.EmplId.History.Where(a => a.ReportType == "type1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> fetch all the reports of type1 for all employees working in the Department with the given Id, ordered by timestamp

Assuming you set up your navigation properties the way I'd expect, you'd probably want something like this:

```
IQueryable<EmployeeHistory> GetAllReportsOfType1(string departmentId)
{
    return context.EmployeeHistory
        .Where(eh => eh.ReportType == "type1" && eh.Employee.Department.DepId == departmentId)
        .OrderBy(eh => eh.TimeStamp);
}
```

It's difficult, without access to your model and database, for me to tell you exactly what the SQL will look like, but it's really easy for you: you can simply call `.ToString()` on the resulting IQueryable.